# Is my "past perfect continuous tense" usage correct?

Tags: grammar, tense

> When I began studying XXX in my senior year, I realized that I had
>   been preparing for it for years unwittingly.

Comment: This is Off Topic proofreading, but yes, your “past perfect continuous tense” usage is fine.Note that idiomatically, native speakers would almost always put adverbial ***unwittingly*** inside the compound verb: *I had **unwittingly** been preparing for it for years* (or *I had been **unwittingly** preparing for it for years*, both are fine). Or you could put it before the entire clause, ***unwittingly[,]** I had been preparing for it for years.* It's just not so good at the end.